# map ultisnips snippet to a keymap

Tags: vim, code-snippets, ultisnips

I know that by default ultisnips snippet are triggered when the `TAB`key is pressed. I also 
know that this trigger key can be changed. However, can a snippet be triggered automatically 
when certain keys are typed. For example, suppose I have the snippet

```
snippet mt "Enter math env"
$ $1 $ $0
endsnippet
```

I can trigger this by typing `m` `t` `TAB`. But can I have this trigger automatically when I type
`m` `t`, and how can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this idea is that now you have to escape any occurrence of `mt` inside a word. Then you say, "okay, it has to be a separate word (mt doesn't exist as such), but now you have to conclude this with Space, and you've won nothing.

Comment: I am not worried about that. I plan to choose key combinations that do not occur together in words.